# How does ASPNET Core resolves the configuration path

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I have the following code:

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    config
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", true);
```

Which works fine in development environment and production too. However if I place this:

```
    Raise<FileNotFoundException>.If(File.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json")),
        $"Could not find the settings file");
```

It raises exception during debug sessions and release sessions (basically when the app is not published and executed from Visual Studio) that file could not be found which is kind of correct because VS2017 does not copy settings file to the debug folder and instead keep them in the source folder. So my question is, 
**how does the dotnet core resolves the configuration path for aspnet core?**

Comment: Not 100% sure but probably using the `IHostingEnvironment Interface` the `ContentRootPath` property

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused on things here. The configuration is pulled by default from the entry point directory. Inside Visual Studio or when running `dotnet run` from the command-line within your project root, everything works fine. Also, when you *publish*, the published directory will contain the configuration files alongside the entrypoint DLL, so this will work fine as well.

What you seem to be talking about is running from the `bin` directory, which is not a supported thing. The bin directory is effectively a cache. It's not a published version of your application, and thus cannot be run as if it is.